# How to do COUNTIFS of values in a Pandas Dataframe and add result to a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got two dataframes looking like this:

`df1`:

|  | omg | odds | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2625 | 27 | 1 |
| 1 | 2625 | 22 | 1 |
| 2 | 2626 | 10 | 0 |
| 3 | 2628 | 15 | 1 |
| 4 | 2628 | 20 | 1 |

`df2`:

|  | omgangar |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2625 |
| 1 | 2626 |
| 2 | 2627 |
| 3 | 2628 |
| 4 | 2629 |

In `df2` I'd like to add a new column that counts the occurrences of `df2[omgangar] in df1[omg]` together with some other conditions (odds between two values and outcome equal to 1).

I've tried this code but it throws an error:

```py
df2['outcome'] = 
sum((df1['omg'] == df2['omgangar']) & (df1['odds'].between(20,30)) & (df1['outcome'] == 1))
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

The desired output of `df2` is:

|  | omgangar | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2625 | 2 |
| 1 | 2626 | 0 |
| 2 | 2627 | 0 |
| 3 | 2628 | 1 |
| 4 | 2629 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter by mask with column `omg` and get counts by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), for new column use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with replace missing not matched values to `0`:

```
s = df1.loc[df1['odds'].between(20,30) & (df1['outcome'] == 1), 'omg'].value_counts()
df2['outcome'] = df2['omgangar'].map(s).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df2)
   omgangar  outcome
0      2625        2
1      2626        0
2      2627        0
3      2628        1
4      2629        0
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use countifs, instead apply the filters first and then merge the dataframes.

First filter `df1` with the two conditions, then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `omg` and aggregate using [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) as follows:

```
s = df1.loc[df['odds'].between(20,30) & (df['outcome'] == 1)].groupby('omg')['odds'].count()
```

This will return a series `s` which looks like this:

```
omg
2625    2
2628    1
Name: odds, dtype: int64
```

Now, [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) `s` with `df2` and fill any resulting NaN values with `0`:

```
df2.merge(df, left_on='omgangar', right_index=True, how='left').fillna(0.0)
```

Result:

```
    omgangar  odds
0       2625   2.0
1       2626   0.0
2       2627   0.0
3       2628   1.0
4       2629   0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use merge and groupby for this task:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'omg': [2625, 2625, 2626, 2628, 2628], 
    'odds': [27, 22, 10, 15, 20], 
    'outcome': [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'omgangar': list(range(2625, 2630))})

df = df2.merge(df1, left_on = 'omgangar', right_on = 'omg', how='left')
df['outcome'] = (df.outcome == 1) & (df.odds.between(20, 30))
df.groupby('omgangar')[['outcome']].agg('sum')
```

```
    outcome
omgangar    
2625    2
2626    0
2627    0
2628    1
2629    0
```